# Finding only the files starting at current directory that have the setuid bit on

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I was asked to find a command that will list only the files starting at the current directory (and under it) that have the setuid bit on. I was told that this was the correct way to do it:

```
find /home/anyuser -type f \( -perm -4000 \)
```

However I get the error:

```
find: paths must precede expression (-perm
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

I was specifically told to use this command, but I'm frustrated why it's not working. I used this command and it didn't give me any errors:

```
find /home/anyuser -type f -perm -4000
```

Would this give me the correct results? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says `(-perm`. So you must have actually typed:

```
find /home/anyuser -type f \(-perm -4000 \)
```

with no space before `-perm`. The space is required.